# How to disable click button when im at the end of the slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transitions

Here is my code, if im on the end of the slider then the right button should disable automatically, and the same thing should happen when im on the initial stage means, if im on "area1" then the left arrow wont work and if I'm on the "area 8" then right arrow shouldn't work

```js
$('.rightArrow').click(function(event) {
    $('.box').animate({'left' : "-=200px"});
});
$('.leftArrow').click(function() {
    $('.box').animate({'left' : "+=200px"});
});
```

```css
.mainRow::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;  /* remove scrollbar space */
    height: 0px;
}
.mainRow::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
}
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
.mainRow {

    overflow-x: scroll !important;
    border-collapse:separate;
    border-spacing:5px 0px;
}

.box {
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
    min-width: 200px;
    max-width: 200px;
    display: table-cell;
    animation: slideBox .5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    position: relative;
}
.arrows {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
.leftArrow {
    position: absolute;
    left: -50px;
    top: 20px;
    font-size: 40px;
}
.rightArrow {
    position: absolute;
    right: -50px;
    top: 20px;
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container wrapper">
  <div class="mainRow">
      <div class="box">area 1</div>
      <div class="box">area 2</div>
      <div class="box">area 3</div>
      <div class="box">area 4</div>
      <div class="box">area 5</div>
      <div class="box">area 6</div>
      <div class="box">area 7</div>
      <div class="box">area 8</div>
  </div>
  <div class="arrows">
      <button type="button" class="leftArrow" id="noclick"> <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i> </button>
      <button type="button" class="rightArrow"> <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**fixed**

probably not best solution if you're planning on changing the number of slides you're using (but in that case you'll have to calculate the maximum `left` possible to check if you want to go further or not).

add a check for `position().left` before you change the position:

```
var truePosition = $('.box').position().left;
$('.rightArrow').click(function(event) {
    if(truePosition > -1415){
        truePosition -= 205;
        $('.box').animate({'left' : "-=205px"});
    }
});
$('.leftArrow').click(function() {
    if(truePosition < 20){
        truePosition += 205;
        $('.box').animate({'left' : "+=205px"});
    }
});
```

check a working example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/35281/)

Comment: Very quick to answer - beat me to the punchline with the exact point I would've liked to make as well :) +1

Comment: thanks man u did it well.  but the problem is sometime its don't work which is really a bad thing for the users.

Comment: hmm i see a problem, don't know if that's what you're talking about, it's due to clicking before previous animation finishes. left me edit it.

Comment: fixed that one.

Comment: for me its perfect but look at the programmers points of view, what would happen if there is more that 8 area's, will that work perfectly as it should. no it won't,

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with one more solution https://jsfiddle.net/znkne887/2/

```js
var boxWidth = $('.box:first-child').width() + 5;
var cnt = 0;
$('.rightArrow').click(function(event) {
    $('.box').animate({'left' : `-=${boxWidth}px`});
    cnt++;
    if(cnt === $('.mainRow').children().length - 1 ){
     $(this).hide();
    }else{
     $(this).show();
    }
    $('.leftArrow').show();
});
$('.leftArrow').click(function() {
    $('.box').animate({'left' : `+=${boxWidth}px`});
    cnt--;
    if(cnt === 0){
     $(this).hide();
    }else{
     $(this).show();
    }
    $('.rightArrow').show();
});
```

```css
.mainRow::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;  /* remove scrollbar space */
    height: 0px;
}
.mainRow::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
}
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.mainRow {
    width: 200px;
    overflow-x: scroll !important;
    border-collapse:separate;
    border-spacing:5px 0px;
}

.box {
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
    min-width: 200px;
    max-width: 200px;
    display: table-cell;
    animation: slideBox .5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    position: relative;
    text-align:center;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.arrows {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index:9;
}
.leftArrow {
    position: absolute;
    left: -35px;
    top: 20px;
    font-size: 40px;
    display:none;
}
.rightArrow {
    position: absolute;
    right: -35px;
    top: 20px;
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container wrapper">
  
  <div class="arrows">
      <button type="button" class="leftArrow" id="noclick"> <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i> </button>
  </div>    
  
  <div class="mainRow">
      <div class="box">area 1</div>
      <div class="box">area 2</div>
      <div class="box">area 3</div>
      <div class="box">area 4</div>
      <div class="box">area 5</div>
      <div class="box">area 6</div>
      <div class="box">area 7</div>
      <div class="box">area 8</div>
  </div>
  <div class="arrows">
      <button type="button" class="rightArrow"> <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: its correct Shiladitya but on my screen only 1 area appearing at a time.

Comment: its perfect for the mobile devices but in desktop screen size its not working, occurs the same problem in desktop size... thanks for your time Aditya

Comment: exactly Aditya. it should cover as much box as device can... but in this case only one area appearing

Comment: Aditya what happening is when im continuously clicking on the right arrow buttons its don't stop but taking the box's away... try themselves by clicking multiple times continuously.

Comment: i know the same thing was happening with the Hallleron codes too. but here now im assuming as we already have that option so why don't we look for a proper solution..

Comment: let me tell you the reason behind this thumbnail slider, i could have download slider by online but that thing will come with lots of unusual codes which is almost impossible to compressor by ourselves, that is why i was making this css thumbnail slide with less jquery code. so we can use it on any web page doesn't matter how many jquery file we have on that page but our this slider will not conflict with any of the jquery file..

Comment: @Samar... Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/znkne887/5/

Comment: Nice Aditya what you did here is fixed its length as "var maxMove = (8)" right?. its good but what if users added move box's all the other box's after the area 8 will not visible on the screen.

Comment: is it possible to increase its length as per the box's. means if there is 12 boxs then the "max move length 8" automatically convert to ("12"). is it possible aditya?? because its gonna be dynamically

Comment: still facing the same problem, on multiple click its not stopping at its end point..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working fiddle for any amount of slides. Click the right arrow until the end and see what happens.

**NOTE:** The button only hides when the last slide is fully visible, so you may have to modify your slider to always move a whole slide.

**EDIT:** Should work for the left button now.

```js
$('.rightArrow').click(function(event) {
 $('.box').animate({'left' : "-=200px"});
 if( $('.box').last().isFullyVisible() ){
        $(this).hide();
   }
    $('.leftArrow').show();
});
$('.leftArrow').click(function() {
  $('.box').animate({'left' : "+=200px"});
  if( $('.box').first().isFullyVisible() ){
    $(this).hide();
  }
        $('.rightArrow').show();
});

$(function(){
  if( $('.box').first().isFullyVisible() ){
    $('.leftArrow').hide();
  }
});



jQuery.fn.isFullyVisible = function(){

 var win = $(window);
 var viewport = {
     top : win.scrollTop(),
     left : win.scrollLeft()
 };

 viewport.right = viewport.left + win.width();
 viewport.bottom = viewport.top + win.height();

 var elemtHeight = this.height();
 elemtHeight = Math.round(elemtHeight);

 var bounds = this.offset();
 bounds.top = bounds.top + elemtHeight;
 bounds.right = bounds.left + this.outerWidth();
 bounds.bottom = bounds.top + this.outerHeight();

 return (!(viewport.right < bounds.left || viewport.left > bounds.right || viewport.bottom < bounds.top || viewport.top > bounds.bottom));

}
```

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.mainRow::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 0px;  /* remove scrollbar space */
        height: 0px;
    }
    .mainRow::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        width: 0px;
        height: 0px;
    }
    .wrapper {
        position: relative;
    }
    .mainRow {

        overflow-x: scroll !important;
        border-collapse:separate;
        border-spacing:5px 0px;
    }

    .box {
        background: #ddd;
        height: 100px;
        min-width: 200px;
        max-width: 200px;
        display: table-cell;
        animation: slideBox .5s;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        position: relative;
    }
    .arrows {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
    }
    .leftArrow {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
        top: 20px;
        font-size: 40px;
    }
    .rightArrow {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0px;
        top: 20px;
        font-size: 40px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container wrapper">
    <div class="mainRow">
        <div class="box">area 1</div>
        <div class="box">area 2</div>
        <div class="box">area 3</div>
        <div class="box">area 4</div>
        <div class="box">area 5</div>
        <div class="box">area 6</div>
        <div class="box">area 7</div>
        <div class="box">area 8</div>
    </div>
    <div class="arrows">
        <button type="button" class="leftArrow" id="noclick"> <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i> </button>
        <button type="button" class="rightArrow"> <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What problem do you mean?

Comment: In the being just click on the left arrow... It will take you to the blank space.... That's the problem is described as a question also...

Comment: I only did it for the right arrow in this example. But you can adapt it the same for the left one.

Comment: Even right arrow is also having problem... When you see the entire last box, you should disable the right arrow button.... But in your case it's adding blank space... Please fix it...

Comment: Okay, you didn't read my answer. The arrow disappears when the WHOLE last slide is fully visible. Since you are just adding a fixed value of 200px each time and do not calculate this value by window size, you will always face this problem. The reason why it is adding free space is because the last div is not 100% visible. There are some pixels still hidden....

Comment: is there any resolution for that?

Comment: thanks Hallleron  u made it, but im facing problem in doing the same thing for the left button as well.. can you please paste here the code for left button also.???

Comment: Yes there are many. As I mentioned, you should calculate the values based on the window width ...